# Indian flapshell turtle not eating

Tags: health, eating, turtles, temperature

I have a baby Indian flapshell turtle (*Lissemys punctata*), around 4-5 months old. I have observed that it has not been consuming its food for the last few days. It is playing fine inside water and also basking under sunlight.

Could the issue of not eating be due to the cold/winter here? Should I consult a veterinarian?

Comment: Are you able to modify your post to give me a little more information.

Tank size,

Substrate,

Temperature of water and basking site,

Filtration system,

UV lighting - coil, tube or MVB (last time it was changed),

Type of food, any vit/min additives (how often).

Housed with any other species?

If you could post pictures of your setup that would be great :)

How long have you had him for? Most problems are related to setup so it's good to rule that out.

Comment: We are keeping it in a bath tub in large size. For basking I have kept a piece of rock so it can bask and sot over there. I have not put any UV light for it and for the case of filteration we are changing the water of the tub every 12 hours so no artificial filters is added. he is allowed to roam in sunlight for 30-35 mins morning and evening. P.S I am based in India.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have consulted the vet they told it was result of heavy cold in this region.