# My turtle won't eat

Tags: health, reptiles, eating, turtles

Why won't my turtle (a spiny turtle), that I've just recently bought, eat? It's been 1 week and the turtle still hasn't eat. The turtle is 12 inch (30 cm) long (I reckon she is quite old). I've tried putting it and it's food in warm water that's appropriate for her, putting her and it's food under the sun, and even tried variety of food, but it still won't eat. There are no signs of swollen eyes or mucus. She never yawns, she barely opens her mouth. She seems sluggish and doesn't move that much. Is she just adapting or there is an illness going on?

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! If you have worries about your animal, please visit a vet. Do not wait for opinions of strangers from the internet!

Comment: What temperature do the water have? Do you know h was the turtle fed by the last owner? Aquatic turtles do only eat in the water, because they can not swallow food without water.

Comment: And maybe you can add a picture of her please?

Comment: WIthout additional information we can not answer this question! Please help by answering the questions, asked in the other comments

Comment: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/16027/indian-flapshell-turtle-not-eating

Comment: What time of the year did this occur? She might be going into hibernation. How long have you had her? I'd try calling the vet if things get worse. Knowing that shes pretty sluggish doesn't seem like a good sign. Is she usally a active? If so call a vet. Somethings clearly wrong.